# Show html text in div in different lines

Tags: python, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a shell in html, user types the command and then shell returns the input, however the output I am getting is on different lines and as should be shown in new lines

This is my image of the output in console
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apeCL.jpg)

but what I am getting in html is completely different, its all on the same line
[Angular Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKDse.jpg)

I want all the text which is `A` in new lines

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<br>` tag

```
a<br>
a<br>
a<br>
a<br>
a<br>
a<br>
a<br>
```

Comment: it will be dynamic text should be on new line

Comment: create for every input a new p-Element. fill this with your A and then add them to the end of your last td with innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using **\n**

`for i in range(1,10):print("A\n")`